# Combine all variables from the groups that a host belongs to

Tags: ansible

When running a playbook for a host, how to access all combined variables for all groups that this host belongs to?

E.g. if have an inventory:

```
all:
  hosts:
    somehost.acme.com
    someotherhost.acme.com
  vars:
    organization: Acme Inc.
us:
  hosts:
    somehost.acme.com
  vars:
    country: US
    city: New York

netherlands:
  hosts:
    someotherhost.acme.com
  vars:
    country: NL
    city: Amsterdam
```

.. and I run a playbook for host `somehost.acme.com` then I would get the variables of `organization`, `country` and `city`.

**UPD**

This is how I access the variables in the playbook:

```
vars:
  organization: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vars.organization }}"
  country: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vars.country }}"
  city: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].vars.city }}"
```

Comment: Hmmm... provide more details. This vars automatically merged by Ansible and available as host facts during runtime.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov yes, you are right. The problem was that I used `.vars.` - should have used `"{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].organization }}"` instead.